# How to rotate ImageView about z axis+ iphone?

Tags: iphone, rotation, cgaffinetransform

I have customized a carousel View(photo gallery) and when i scroll I want the images to rotate  towards the back of the screen. To give the impression that the images are moving in a circular way.

`CGAffineTransformRotate` just rotates the image on the x axis. I want to rotate it in such a way that finally the image is perpendicular to the screen.

Any thoughts people?

Edit:
** I dont think my question was clear. What i want is a image on the screen to rotate and be perpendicular to the screen. It should be visible only as a straight line.(or wen it is at 45' as a slant image)?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use CATransform3DRotate. You can see a basic example here: 
[CATransform3DRotate and UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295114/catransform3drotate-and-uiimageview)

Hope this helps,
Moszi

Comment: I tried this but anything i do, it just Cuts the image. Maybe i have not understood the property correctly. So used CGAffineTransform but with this i get two problems. 1. Unable to retrieve the original image 2. When i use animation, the whole transition becomes very jerky